# c# WebClient DownloadFileAsync() does not throw errors

Tags: c#, webclient

I am successfully downloading files with below code. Since I want them to be downloaded on Application Startup I do not want to block anything -> async.

However I am facing the problem that even when the URI path is complete nonsense it will generate me an empty file, instead of raising the error like stated in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can anyone help me?

```
private void DownloadDocuments()
    {
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Log("load1");
                myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(documentsUri + documentActivation), documentspath + "\\" + documentActivation);

            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Log("Guide Activation Download failed.");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Log("Guide Activation could not be saved.");
            }
        }
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        { 
            try
            {
                Log("load2");
                myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(documentsUri + documentFloating), documentspath + "\\" + documentFloating);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Log("Guide Floating Download failed.");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Log("Guide Floating could not be saved.");
            }
        }
        using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Log("load3");
                myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(documentsUri + documentSeat), documentspath + "\\" + documentSeat);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                Log("Guide Seat Download failed.");
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Log("Guide Seat could not be saved.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, you should probably use `UriBuilder` instead of manually concatenating Uris...

Comment: You should use await with Task to handle the exceptions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534704/how-to-deal-with-exceptions-when-using-webclient-downloadfileasync

Comment: If you `await` the three `DownloadFileAsync` calls, the files will be retrieved one after the other instead of being downloaded in parallel.

Comment: Why not use `HttpClient`? You can reuse the same instance for those three requests. (You could probably reuse the same instance of your `WebClient` also.)

Comment: @Bouke DownloadFileAsync cannot be awaited since it is not returning anything

Comment: @Kenneth K.  `WebClient` does not support parallel downloads, I will look through `HttpClient`, thank you.

Comment: @wulfithewulf Have you checked my answer? It does download files in parallel using *WebClient*. However, I also recommend *HttpClient* but my solution can be easily reworked to use that.

Comment: yeah I tried and it worked, I did some adjustments to fit best, but now it works as I wnated it. What I referred to is, that you cannot have parallel downloading with the same resource (in the same `using` statement)

Comment: As you need to download only 3 files, creating a separate *WebClient* instance for each request doesn't matter much. If you downloaded, say, 100 files, then [a single, re-used *HttpClient*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178220/is-httpclient-safe-to-use-concurrently) would be definitely advisable.

Comment: yes you are definitely right but, for this special situation, for which I can foresee will not change, the WebClient seems less work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*WebClient.DownloadFileAsync* doesn't throw exceptions on HTTP request failures. You need to subscribe to the *DownloadFileCompleted* event to get notified of errors.

However, I don't recommend messing with event handler callbacks once we have the task-based async/await feature in C#: *WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync* is much more convenient to use.

With your comment about parallel processing in mind, you can do something like this:

```
static async Task DownloadDocumentAsync(Uri uri, string fileName)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, fileName);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Log($"Downloading {uri} failed. {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            Log($"Saving {uri} to {fileName} failed. File is in use.");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your logic at application startup:

```
var baseUri = new Uri(documentsUri);
var downloadTasks = new[]
{
    DownloadDocumentAsync(new Uri(baseUri, documentActivation), Path.Combine(documentspath, documentActivation)),
    DownloadDocumentAsync(new Uri(baseUri, documentFloating), Path.Combine(documentspath, documentFloating)),
    DownloadDocumentAsync(new Uri(baseUri, documentSeat), Path.Combine(documentspath, documentSeat)),
};

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(downloadTasks);
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    // handle the case when some of the download tasks failed
}
```

This way the download tasks executes parallel but *Task.WaitAll* blocks until all of the tasks are completed. If you want to stay async, you need `await Task.WhenAll` instead.

Comment: thank you it worked. I do not need to try catch the `Task.WhenAll` since I do not throw the error again, since the only handling I would do, would be to delete the File with which occured an errror. But yeah thank you :)